# What does it mean "weakly-referenced object no longer exists"?

Tags: python

I am running a Python code and I get the following error message:

```
Exception exceptions.ReferenceError: 'weakly-referenced object no longer exists' in <bound method crawler.__del__ of <searchengine.crawler instance at 0x2b8c1f99ef80>> ignored
```

Does anybody know what can it means?

P.S.
This is the code which produce the error:

```
import sqlite

class crawler:

  def __init__(self,dbname):
    tmp = sqlite.connect(dbname)
    self.con = tmp.cursor()

  def __del__(self):
    self.con.close()

crawler =  crawler('searchindex.db')
```

Answer (score 61, accepted):

A normal AKA strong reference is one that keeps the referred-to object alive: in CPython, each object keeps the number of (normal) references to it that exists (known as its "reference count" or RC) and goes away as soon as the RC reaches zero (occasional generational mark and sweep passes also garbage-collect "reference loops" once in a while).

When you don't want an object to stay alive just because another one refers to it, then you use a "weak reference", a special variety of reference that doesn't increment the RC; see [the docs](http://docs.python.org/library/weakref.html?highlight=weakref#module-weakref) for details.  Of course, since the referred-to object CAN go away if not otherwise referred to (the whole purpose of the weak ref rather than a normal one!-), the referring-to object needs to be warned if it tries to use an object that's gone away -- and that alert is given exactly by the exception you're seeing.

In your code...:

```
def __init__(self,dbname):
    tmp = sqlite.connect(dbname)
    self.con = tmp.cursor()

def __del__(self):
    self.con.close()
```

`tmp` is a normal reference to the connection... but it's a local variable, so it goes away at the end of `__init__`. The (peculiarly named) cursor `self.con` stays, BUT it's internally implemented to only hold a WEAK ref to the connection, so the connection goes away when `tmp` does.  So in `__del__` the call to `.close` fails (since the cursor needs to use the connection in order to close itself).

Simplest solution is the following tiny change:

```
def __init__(self,dbname):
    self.con = sqlite.connect(dbname)
    self.cur = self.con.cursor()

def __del__(self):
    self.cur.close()
    self.con.close()
```

I've also taken the opportunity to use con for connection and cur for cursor, but Python won't mind if you're keen to swap those (you'll just leave readers perplexed).

Answer (score 2):

The code is referring to an instance which has already been garbage collected.
To avoid circular references you can use a weak reference which isn't enough to prevent garbage collection. In this case there is a weakref.proxy (http://docs.python.org/library/weakref.html#weakref.proxy) to a searchengine.crawler object.

Comment: Do circular references really prevent GC in python?!

Comment: I've read that `__del__()` prevents GC in case of circular references when it's written in Python.

Comment: Bastien is right: http://www.python.org/doc/3.0/reference/datamodel.html#object.__del__ which states: <<Circular references which are garbage are detected when the option cycle detector is enabled (it’s on by default), but can only be cleaned up if there are no Python- level __del__() methods involved. Refer to the documentation for the gc module for more information about how __del__() methods are handled by the cycle detector, particularly the description of the garbage value.>>

Answer (score 0):

Weak references are a form of reference that does not prevent the garbage collector from disposing the referenced object.  If you want to guarantee that the object will continue to exist, you should use a strong (normal) reference.

Otherwise, there is no guarantee that the object will or will not exist after all the normal references have gone out of scope.

Comment: The problem is that i do not know what "weak" or "strong" reference means. I do not even know what the reference means.