# Passing mySQL cursor as return type in a python function

Tags: python, mysql-python

I am connecting to mysql db from python using standard mysql.connector driver.

I defined below function to create a cursor object in order to execute any db queries/DMLs

```
import mysql.connector as msc
    def mem_conn():
            cnx = msc.connect(user='test',password='test',host='mysql.testdb.com', database='test')
            curA = cnx.cursor(buffered=True)
            return curA
```

I make calls from a different function to get the cursor handle(curA)  that I can use to run my DML/Queries inside that function. However, my code ends up in an error when I use this solution and gives out

> File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/mysql/connector/cursor.py",
>   line 482, in execute
>       if not self._connection: ReferenceError: weakly-referenced object no longer exists [m

However, if I use the same code to connect to db and use it in the same function, it works fine.

What am I getting wrong here and what's generally accepted way to do things if I want to conenct to my db at multiple places inside my program. Transaction volume is low but I need to connect to db to read/write at lot of places inside my code.

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Check this out. [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1482141/what-does-it-mean-weakly-referenced-object-no-longer-exists](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1482141/what-does-it-mean-weakly-referenced-object-no-longer-exists)

Answer (score 1):

I wrote similar script in python3 using sqlalchemy. See if this helps.

### sqlalchemyconnection.py

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import sqlalchemy


def dbconn(dbname="test"):
    """ Loads login credentials from text file.
        Passes `test` db as default parameter if db name is not passed by calling script.
        Returns connection object back to calling script.
    """
    try:
        login_info = open("dblogin").read()
        login_info = login_info.split()
        hostname = login_info[0]
        username = login_info[1]
        password = login_info[2]

        try:
            engine_str = 'mysql+mysqlconnector://{}:{}@{}/{}'.format(
                username,
                password,
                hostname,
                dbname
            )
            print(engine_str)
            engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine(engine_str, echo=False,
                                              encoding='utf-8')

            connection_obj = engine.connect()

            return connection_obj
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
    except FileNotFoundError:
        print("dblogin file not found")
```

### test.py

```
from sqlalchemyconnection import dbconn


def test():
    conn = dbconn('tesdb')
    print(conn)

test()
```

### Output: Prints the object for conn.

```
<sqlalchemy.engine.base.Connection object at 0x000000000401FF98>
```

Comment: This solved my weakly-referenced error. Previously I was using mysql.connector.connect().