# Why is my Python mysql class __init__ function trying to overload the mysql package __init__ function?

Tags: python, mysql, oop

I would like to create a simple mysql connection class for my python scripts. Intended usage of the class in `script.py`:

```
import db_connection

db = db_connection.DBConnection()
db.get_cursor()
```

The class itself is in the script `db_connect.py`:

```
import mysql.connector

class DBConnection:

def __init__(self):
    self.__host="192.168.1.22"
    self.__port="3306"
    self.__user="somename"
    self.__passwd="somepw"
    self.__database="mydbname"

def __connect(self):
    con = mysql.connector.connect(
    self.__host,
    self.__port,
    self.__user,
    self.__passwd,
    self.__database
    )

    print("connected.")
    return con

def get_cursor(self):
    con = self.__connect()
    cursor = con.cursor(dictionary=True)
    return cursor
```

I get the following errors:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/.../script.py", line 14, in <module>
    db.get_cursor()
  File "C:\...\db_connection.py", line 26, in get_cursor
    con = self.__connect()
  File "C:\...\db_connection.py", line 13, in __connect
    con = mysql.connector.connect(
  File "C:\...\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\__init__.py", line 219, in connect
    return MySQLConnection(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\...\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\connection.py", line 64, in __init__
    super(MySQLConnection, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
TypeError: __init__() takes 1 positional argument but 6 were given

Process finished with exit code 1
```

There seems to be an issue with the **init** function in my class and the mysql package **init** function. I am too unskilled in Python to understand what I am doing wrong, hence your help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no question of your class' `__init__` method hiding that of `MySQLConnection`. The problem is that you pass your arguments as positional arguments, whereas [`mysql.connector.connect`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-connectargs.html) requires them to be passed as keyword arguments like:

```
con = mysql.connector.connect(
    host=self.__host,
    port=self.__port,
    user=self.__user,
    password=self.__passwd,
    database=self.__database
)
```

You may also refer to the documentation for some [examples](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-example-connecting.html).

As pointed out by Matthias, two leading underscores are not required here (rarely required in code that normal users write). To mark these variables as internal to your class, you would normally use a single underscore, i.e.:

```
def __init__(self):
    self._host="192.168.1.22"
    self._port="3306"
    self._user="somename"
    self._passwd="somepw"
    self._database="mydbname"
```

You get a further error

> ReferenceError: weakly-referenced object no longer exists

because your connection is only temporary and exists within the scope of your `get_cursor` method. The connection is closed at the end of that method. You may resolve this by storing the connection on your class, which keeps a reference to the open connection, something like:

```
class DBConnection:

    def __init__(self):
        self._host="192.168.1.22"
        self._port="3306"
        self._user="somename"
        self._passwd="somepw"
        self._database="mydbname"
        self.con = None

    def _connect(self):
        self.con = mysql.connector.connect(
            host=self._host,
            port=self._port,
            user=self._user,
            password=self._passwd,
            database=self._database
        )

        print("connected.")

    def get_cursor(self):
        if not self.con:
            self._connect()
        return self.con.cursor(dictionary=True)
```

More detail about this `ReferenceError` can be found in [What does it mean "weakly-referenced object no longer exists"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1482141/what-does-it-mean-weakly-referenced-object-no-longer-exists).

Comment: BTW the leading two underscores seem overkill. If you want to mark the attributes for internal use, a single leading underscore is sufficient.

Comment: @Matthias I have updated my answer to include this.

Comment: Thank you, that resolved the problem of the _connect function. Now, however, when using the db_connect object, getting the cursor and running a query on it, I get this error: `ReferenceError: weakly-referenced object no longer exists`: `db = db_connection.DBConnection()
cursor = db.get_cursor()
cursor.execute("SELECT * from tablea;")`

Comment: @Siedler Please see my edit. You are getting this error because your connection is closed once your `get_cursor` method has finished executing. This is because the cursor only holds a weak reference to the underlying connection.