# Unable to add kivymd's MDTextField in MDGridLayout

Tags: python, android, python-3.x, kivy, kivy-language

I am new to kivy framework, however I am trying to make a simple login screen in which there will be a text field and a button

My Python code is:

```
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen,\
                                    ScreenManager

from kivy.lang import Builder

class Project (MDApp):
    def build (self):
        return Builder.load_file('main.kv')
    
Project().run()
```

and *main.kv* file is:

```
Screen:
    MDBoxLayout:
        orientation:'vertical'
        md_bg_color:1,0,0,1
        MDToolbar:
        MDGridLayout:
            cols:1
            adaptive_height: True
            MDLabel:
                text:'Manic'
                halign:'center'
            MDTextField:
```

I am getting the following error:

> [INFO   ] [Logger      ] Record log in /storage/emulated/0/@tsmile/projects/pro_two/.kivy/logs/kivy_21-03-19_38.txt
> [INFO   ] [Kivy        ] v1.11.1
> [INFO   ] [Kivy        ] Installed at "/data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/aarch64-linux-android/lib/python3.8/site-packages/kivy/**init**.py"
> [INFO   ] [Python      ] v3.8.3 (default, May 27 2020, 02:08:17)
> [GCC 9.3.0]
> [INFO   ] [Python      ] Interpreter at "/data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/aarch64-linux-android/bin/python3"
> [INFO   ] [Logger      ] Purge log fired. Analysing...
> [INFO   ] [Logger      ] Purge 15 log files
> [INFO   ] [Logger      ] Purge finished!
> [INFO   ] [KivyMD      ] v0.104.1
> [INFO   ] [Factory     ] 184 symbols loaded
> [INFO   ] [Image       ] Providers: img_tex, img_dds, img_sdl2, img_pil, img_gif (img_ffpyplayer ignored)
> [INFO   ] [Window      ] Provider: sdl2
> [INFO   ] [GL          ] Using the "OpenGL ES 2" graphics system
> [INFO   ] [GL          ] Backend used 
> [INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL version <b'OpenGL ES 3.2 v1.r20p0-01rel0.5a1b26bb5d6f760a7fe004c7d2efd431'>
> [INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL vendor <b'ARM'>
> [INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL renderer <b'Mali-G72 MP3'>
> [INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL parsed version: 3, 2
> [INFO   ] [GL          ] Texture max size <8192>
> [INFO   ] [GL          ] Texture max units <16>
> [INFO   ] [Window      ] auto add sdl2 input provider
> [INFO   ] [Window      ] virtual keyboard not allowed, single mode, not docked
> [INFO   ] [Text        ] Provider: sdl2
> [INFO   ] [GL          ] NPOT texture support is available
> [INFO   ] ***********app started***********
> [INFO   ] main.kv loaded
> [INFO   ] security.kv loaded
> [WARNING] [Base        ] Unknown  provider
> [INFO   ] [Base        ] Start application main loop
> [INFO   ] [Base        ] Leaving application in progress...
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "/storage/emulated/0/@tsmile/projects/pro_two/main.py", line 36, in 
> Project().run()
>
> File "/data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/aarch64-linux-android/lib/python3.8/site-packages/kivy/app.py", line 855, in run
> runTouchApp()
>
> File "/data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/aarch64-linux-android/lib/python3.8/site-packages/kivy/base.py", line 504, in runTouchApp
> EventLoop.window.mainloop()
>
> File "/data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/aarch64-linux-android/lib/python3.8/site-packages/kivy/core/window/window_sdl2.py", line 747, in mainloop
> self._mainloop()
>
> File "/data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/aarch64-linux-android/lib/python3.8/site-packages/kivy/core/window/window_sdl2.py", line 479, in _mainloop
> EventLoop.idle()
>
> File "/data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/aarch64-linux-android/lib/python3.8/site-packages/kivy/base.py", line 339, in idle
> Clock.tick()
> File "/data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/aarch64-linux-android/lib/python3.8/site-packages/kivy/clock.py", line 591, in tick
> self._process_events()
> File "kivy/_clock.pyx", line 384, in kivy._clock.CyClockBase._process_events
> File "kivy/_clock.pyx", line 414, in kivy._clock.CyClockBase._process_events
> File "kivy/_clock.pyx", line 412, in kivy._clock.CyClockBase._process_events
> File "kivy/_clock.pyx", line 154, in kivy._clock.ClockEvent.tick
> File "kivy/_clock.pyx", line 86, in kivy._clock.ClockEvent.get_callback
> File "/data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/aarch64-linux-android/lib/python3.8/site-packages/kivy/weakmethod.py", line 56, in is_dead
> return self.proxy is not None and not bool(dir(self.proxy))
>
> ReferenceError: weakly-referenced object no longer exists

I am getting reference error error in which it is saying that

> Weakly referenced objects do not exist

Can anyone suggest that how can I add MDTextField to MDGridLayout?

And please also tell me that why such kind of error occurs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I corrected your layout a bit to take your wishes into account. The .py stays the same, the updated .kv is here:

```
Screen:
MDBoxLayout:
    orientation:'vertical'
    md_bg_color:1,0,0,1
    MDToolbar:
        pos_hint_y: 0
    GridLayout:
        cols:1
        adaptive_height: True
        MDLabel:
            text:'Manic'
            halign:'center'
        BoxLayout:
            cols: 2
            rows: 1

            MDLabel:
                halign:'center'
                size_hint_y: 0.4
                size_hint_x: 0.3

            MDTextFieldRect:
                size_hint_y: 0.4
            MDFlatButton:
                text: "Test"
                md_bg_color: 1,1,0,1
                size_hint_y: 0.4
                size_hint_x: 0.3
        MDLabel:
            halign:'center'
            size_hint_y: 0.2
```

As for the weakly referenced object:

A weak reference is, on a basic level, a reference to an object, which will be removed by garbage collection. If you want a bit more information about it, I suggest you check out @AlexMartelli's detailed answer on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1482141/what-does-it-mean-weakly-referenced-object-no-longer-exists) post.

Comment: Thanks a lot Now it's working fine. But I still need to know more about **weakly refferance errors**. 