# Weakly referenced object no longer exists when trying to create a "destructor"

Tags: python, mysql

am trying to create a MySQL database adaptor class for myself, and want to clean up when the object is destroyed.

The init and del methods look something like this:

```
    def __init__(self, database):
        self.connection = mysql.connector.connect(
            host = "xxx",
            database = self.database,
            port = "xxx",
            user = "xxx",
            password = "xxx",
        )
        self.cursor = self.connection.cursor()

    def __del__(self):
        self.cursor.close()
        self.connection.close()
```

But `self.cursor.close()` in `__del__()` will complain about a: `ReferenceError: weakly-referenced object no longer exists`

I've read the most related SO post I can find: [What does it mean "weakly-referenced object no longer exists"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1482141/what-does-it-mean-weakly-referenced-object-no-longer-exists)

And as far as I can tell I don't have any of the same issues that caused the asker of that question to be facing this weakly referenced object error.

Some context on the app:
Using mysql.connector
Being instantiated while running a Flask app. (don't know if quitting does anything unique)

Thanks all.

Comment: Could cursor or connection be closed already when `__del__` is called?

Comment: Not by me. Another note: This same class will work fine when in a standalone script, but when instantiated via a flask server (then when I ctrl-c the server) then I get this error.