# Strategies for debugging/finding weak references in python?

Tags: python, debugging, weak-references

In trying to pickle an object I get the following error:

```py
ReferenceError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
/Users/rhys/phd-work/tmp-design-test.py in <cell line: 125>()
    212 # # %%
    214 with open("test-pipe.pt", "wb") as f:
--> 215     pickle.dump(form_pipe, f)
    216     # torch.save(form_pipe, f)
    218 with open("test-pipe.pt", "rb") as f:

ReferenceError: weakly-referenced object no longer exists
```

I am not using `weakref` at any point and cannot work out which object is weakly referenced. If I apply a cleaning stage that removes some NaNs from the data before fitting the object (`sklearn.Pipeline` with a custom transformer) then I can pickle the object.

Without knowing which object is weakly referenced my efforts to debug this have stalled and I was wondering if there are any tools or strategies to debug this more effectively?

Comment: you can look at this link **https://stackoverflow.com/q/1482141/14792476**

Comment: thanks! I have a better understanding but still am not sure how to effectively locate the object for which the weak reference exists.